# How to print a histogram from dictionary data with builtins

Tags: python, python-3.x, graph, charts

Hello I am new to python and need to print a graph with the following data:

The height of each bar being the count of each type of word. lets assume we had three buckets (a,b, and c) and in each we had a number of apples:

```
  a - 1
  b - 3
  c - 2
```

So if we were to chart this out it might look something like:

```
  3_x_
  2_xx
  1xxx
  .abc
```

use '_' as a place holder for the cell that does not have any data and 'x' as the marker for data. How can I draw a graph from this data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're new to Python, I highly recommend poking around their library documentation: http://docs.python.org/3/library/. Here's some code for this problem specifically:

```
def chart(dictionary):
    height = max(dictionary.values())      # Figures out how tall the diagram needs
    for i in range(height):                # to be, then loops once per level.
            current_height = height - i          # Next line creates a string 
        s = "{0}".format(current_height)         # containing the height number.
        for value in dictionary.values():         # This loop decides for each entry
            if value >= current_height:           # whether to use a 'x' or a '_'.
                s += 'x'
            else:
                s += '_'
        print(s)
    s = '.'                          # These two lines create the lowermost string
    for key in dictionary.keys():    # with labels.
        s += key
    print(s)
```

This code is very specialized for the above problem, but it should give you a good idea of where you need to go.

Comment: Thanks that did it. I am taking your advice and reading up on the library information. Thank you much. Your assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Glad to hear it! Stack Overflow tip: when an answer is right, click on the outlined check-mark next to the answer so it turns green. That way, everyone else knows it worked for you.